# Approaches to solving $(1-x^2)y''+2xy'-2y = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What are some approaches to solving differential equations like the one below?

> $(1-x^2)y''+2xy'-2y = 0$

For instance, using power series would be one way, but what other methods exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2x\frac{dy}{dx}-2y = 0$$
ODE of homogeneous kind. The usual change of function is $y(x)=xu(x)$

$y'=xu'+u \quad;\quad y''=xu''+2u'\quad\to\quad (1-x^2)(xu''+2u')+2x(xu'+u)-2xu=0$
$$x(1-x^2)u''+2u'=0$$
$$\frac{u''}{u'}=\frac{2}{x(x^2-1)}=-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2x}{x^2-1}$$
$$u'=c_1\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}$$
$$u=c_1(x+\frac{1}{x})+c_2$$
$$y(x)=c_1(x^2+1)+c_2x$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Put $1-x^2 = t$ and differentiate and put back in your ODE